# INDEX MATCH result is always the same

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, excel-formula

I have created a macro to index match some values between two sheets.. However, even if the index match works, it only prints the same result.. I am providing this part of the code with the index match order.

```
For Each cell2 In ws1.Range("AE2:AE" & lastrow3)
cell2.Formula = "=INDEX('Map'!H:H,MATCH('SAPBW_DOWNLOAD'!AD2,'Map'!G:G,FALSE))"
Next cell2
```

Comment: The match `'SAPBW_DOWNLOAD'!AD2` will always be the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop over the cells, why not just use this?

```
ws1.Range("AE2:AE" & lastrow3).Formula = "=INDEX('Map'!H:H,MATCH('SAPBW_DOWNLOAD'!AD2,'Map'!G:G,FALSE))"
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! do you know how I can add an .NumberFormat = 0# in this line of code?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas You're welcome! Yes, you can add a number format after inserting the formula like this...ws1.Range("AE2:AE" & lastrow3).NumberFormat = "0.00". Change the number format as per your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the same formula in all cells. I imagine you might want something like this:

```
For Each cell2 In ws1.Range("AE2:AE" & lastrow3)
    cell2.Formula = "=INDEX('Map'!H:H,MATCH('SAPBW_DOWNLOAD'!AD" & cell2.Row & ",'Map'!G:G,FALSE))"
Next cell2
```

Comment: @sktneer has a better answer.